# Py2exe does not compile Pandas read_excel

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, py2exe, setup.py

I am experiencing a problem with py2exe and pandas in Python 2.7.7 on Windows (version installed with Anaconda distribution).

I would like to create an executable that:

1. Ask you to insert the name of the Excel file to be read
2. Print or use elements from a column to perform other operations

Here is a simplified form of my code name `test.py`

```
from pandas import read_excel

file_name_db = input('Insert file name (e.g. "database1.xls"): ')

data = read_excel(file_name_db, sheet_name_db=0, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])    

print data.unit

raw_input("Press enter to exit")
```

Then I use this `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup

import py2exe

import pandas

setup(options = {"py2exe":{"includes": ["zmq.backend.cython"],"excludes": ["zmq.libzmq"], "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll","HID.DLL", "w9xpopen.exe", "libzmq.pyd"]}}, console = [{'script': 'test2.py'}])
```

Finally I simply perform in the cmd window `python setup.py py2exe`

Note that all the options in `setup()` have been tested to avoid all the `.dll` compiling problems.

Results:

1. py2exe generates without warnings or errors a `test.exe` in `dist` folder
2. `test.exe` does not run although `test.py` correctly works in Spyder
3. `test.exe` does not run even when I insert `from pandas import read_excel` in `test.py` but I do not ask for any `input` file
4. In the case 2. or 3. when I double-click `test.exe` a black command window appear with a blinking cursor for 10-15 seconds, then a rapid message appears and the window instaneously closes. (I am not able to read what the message says and I am not able to find any log file in `build` or `dist` folders)
5. Note that `test.exe` correctly runs with modules like `numpy` or `datetime` but without `pandas`

I hope I have clearly explained the issue.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort to help me solving this problem!

Roberto

Comment: Are you asking for the name of an Excel file in a console window ? That might be part of the problem. The exe may just open and close the console window faster than you can read it Can use a gui dialog box instead ? If you aren't familiar with Tkinter or similar, google 'python easy gui' for a very simply gui framework that will allow you to check that out.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am asking for. Anyway, the point is that even if I do not ask for an input file (i.e. I just import pandas in the script) the `.exe` does not work. Thanks for the hint, I will try to follow your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to specify the matplotlib datafiles in your setup.py.  At least that is the error I encountered when I tried your example.

Here is my test.py:

```py
from pandas import read_excel

file_name_db = raw_input('Insert file name (e.g. "database1.xls"): ')
data = read_excel(file_name_db, sheet_name_db=0, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])    
print data
raw_input("Press enter to exit")
```

Here is my setup.py:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import pandas
import matplotlib

setup(options = {
    "py2exe":
        {
            "includes": ["zmq.backend.cython"],
            "excludes": ["zmq.libzmq"], 
            "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll","HID.DLL", "w9xpopen.exe", "libzmq.pyd"]
        }
    },
    data_files=matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles(),
    console = [{'script': 'test.py'}]
    )
```

I had to edit the test.py code to get it to run.  I added the "data_files=" line to setup.py.  Both test.py and the built test.exe work for me now.

### How did I find the answer?

In order to debug this I ran the test.exe from the command line, not by double clicking on it.  That way you will see the output, rather than a console that flashes up and then disappears.  When I did that, I saw the error about matplotlib datafiles which led me to google and the solution.

### Ref the import problem

Apologies but I can't reply to comments yet so I edited my post.  It may be that you have different versions of components installed to me.  I googled that error and there didn't appear to be any obvious solution. I have python v2.7.5 (via activestate), pandas 0.14.1 (via scipy stack 14.8.27)

Comment: I have tried your solution.
The file `main.exe` has been correctly generated.
I have executed `main.exe` from the command line and here is the traceback:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
    File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 45, in <module>
    File "pandas\io\api.pyc", line 15, in <module>
    File "pandas\io\gbq.pyc", line 10, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to indent the answer in the correct way, I put here the message error in code form:
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 59, in <module>   File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 45, in <module>   File "pandas\io\api.pyc", line 15, in <module>   File "pandas\io\gbq.pyc", line 10, in <module>    ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`